# Autograd "ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence" when computing norm.logpdf partial derivative

Tags: python, autograd

I am trying to compute the partial derivative of the log pdf of a normal distribution with autograd as in the following code :

```
import autograd.scipy.stats as stat 
import autograd.numpy as np
from autograd import grad

def f(x, lc, sc):
    return stat.norm.logpdf(x, loc= lc, scale = sc)

grad_f = grad(f, argnum=1)

grad_f(-1.0, 1.)
```

and I get the following error message :

```
"ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence".
```

I believe that autograd knows how to handle gradients of the `norm.logpdf` since it is an in-built function and no other vector assignments have been made...